# Magento: Admin panel menu not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, drop-down-menu

My magento  1.7.0.2 admin panel drop down menu was working before a day perfectly and i didn't made any change in setting and core files of admin panel.

but the problem is that my admin panel meunu is not working.i was tried out all solution like js folder permission set to `777` or `755` and i was replaced all js files with same version of Magento ver. 1.7.0.2.But its not working.

When i see in console of browser i am getting following error of js.

so how can i resolve it.I am very much stuck here.

[image: Error in console]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you have a BOM or something like that in your JS files. Try disabling the merging/minifying of the js files so you can see in which file you have the problem. If you cannot access the system>configuration>developper to set it, you can change it directly in the database.

In core_config_data, it is the key : dev/js/merge_files.

Comment: can put it 0 ins ted of 1

Comment: it working i have set 0 and and cleared all cache from var/cache nice answer but what is the issue with js if i merge it

Comment: It is difficult to say without access to the files by themselves but probably an encoding problem.

Comment: Fine by the way great answer